# In what ways is Rust a "concurrent" language?

Tags: concurrency, rust

Rust is advertised as a "concurrent" language, what does this mean specifically and how is it different from other languages such as C++?

Answer (score 11):

It might mean two things :

**Capability of concurrent programming**

Rust provides standard libraries for creation and running of multiple concurrent executions. Mostly through threading. But this is nothing special as most modern languages, including C++, provide the same standard threading libraries.

So I would say this is not what the advertising means.

**Safety of concurrent programming**

This is area where Rust is unique. Due to Rust's type system and strict memory model, Rust creators argue that if your code compiles, you are guaranteed there there are no common concurrent errors in your code. Things like deadlocks or stale data, which might be common in other language's concurrent code are unheard of in Rust code.

But this comes at a price of making creation of such code much more complicated, as satisfying the strict compiler rules requires lots of in-depth knowledge and experience with Rust's type system and memory model.

This becomes even more important, as debugging and fixing concurrent errors is one of the most difficult parts of writing concurrent code. So having system that guarantees no such errors would be seen as huge selling point.

Comment: Rust doesn't protect from deadlocks. It protect you specifically from data races, i.e. the low-level unpredictability of accessing the same memory location from multiple threads at the same time where at least one access is a write. You can still deadlock, livelock, starve threads, or have larger-scale logical race conditions. Data races are the key target here because they are the hardest to debug. If two threads deadlock, it's usually quite easy to find out where and why - they are blocked in their failure state. A data race OTOH may only show symptoms long after the fact.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: it's easy when it's only two threads involved--but you can get a deadlock involving an arbitrary number of threads, as long as there's a cycle in their graph of resource dependencies. When you have a few dozen threads running on different processors involved, proper detection can be more difficult.

Comment: @JerryCoffin But the threads are at least at the point where they deadlocked, not run on to somewhere, leaving corrupt state behind.